# Creating new column in pandas by multiplying existing column with decimal number

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create new column in pandas with:

```
cars.carPowerHP = cars.carPower * 1,341
```

I get error:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1,341` is a 2-tuple `(1, 341)`, not a floating point number.

You mean

```py
autiDF1['carPowerHP'] =  autiDF1['carPower'] * 1.341
```

Comment: Slap in a face...blah, I know I tried that initially and it gave me some weird error, I've reset index and kept trying afterwards with 1,341...well thank you.

Comment: No worries. Sometimes it's the silliest mistakes :)